# Applying the formula to determine the barcode - Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, barcode

How to write the code to apply the formula to the image and the result is low-pass filtered. The red region is the highest intensity which corresponds to the barcode.

Formula: 
[image: Formula]

Original image: 
[image: Original]

Processed Image: [image: Localization of Barcode]

**edited** How to plotting the points??

**edited**  Plotting the Points: [image: Plot the points]

Comment: How to write the coding of this??

Comment: Not trying to be rude, but if you don't know how to implement a derivative filter in matlab, you should be reading books on image processing (using matlab). Piecing basics like this together from stackoverflow questions is bound to be a very frustrating experience.

Comment: I do did some research on that for weeks ago but I don't know how to write the coding!! Sorry if this is dumb question but I really try my best to find the answer!! No hard feeling!! :)

PS. Just my though!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to agree with nikie that you should be working from a book if you are at this basic level, but here is an answer anyway.

```
I = imread('your_image');
# convert I to grayscale double as appropriate using rgb2gray(), double(), etc.

# calculate the gradients and the formula you provided
[dIx, dIy] = gradient(I);
B = abs(dIx) - abs(dIy);

# do your low-pass filtering
H = fspecial('gaussian', 20, 10);
C = imfilter(B, H);

imagesc(C); colorbar;
```

Good luck! Make sure you understand this code before making copypasta.

Comment: Thanks for the code!! I can understand that!! Just that I don't know how to write it!!

Comment: How can I coded the program to read vertical and horizontal barcode??

Comment: Well, just step back a bit and consider your formula. You are taking the horizontal gradient image (dIx) and subtracting the vertical gradient image (dIy). To find vertical barcodes, you can just repeat the process with those two terms switched. Finding barcodes at angles will be a bit more involved :).

Comment: I also think finding barcodes at angles is more necessary for the program to be better. Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: I do have some ideas, but it depends on how fast you need this to run, etc. I also noticed you edited the question to add something about plotting end/mid points of the barcode. You should start new questions instead of editing old ones after they are answered; they will get much more attention.

Comment: Can run in realtime would be the best!! Anyway thanks for the advice, I will repost the question. Thank you!!